# How can I filter a ManyToManyField against the current User in the Browsable API in DRF?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have 2 models, `Todo` and a `Tag`. Todo has a ManyToMany relationship with Tag. When adding new Todos from the Browsable API, I want to be able to see only the Tags added by the current user as the available options in the multiselect. Currently, it shows all the added Tags, irrespective of who added them. I want to limit the options to only show the Tags added by the current user. (Authentication is setup already)

The models:

```
class Todo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    due_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name='todos')

    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='todos')

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='created_tags')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

The Serializer:

```
class TodoCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): #This is the one being used for a POST
    class Meta:
        model = models.Todo
        fields = ('title', 'description', 'due_at', 'tags')
```

Is there some serializer field or some other way to specify which queryset to use in the Serializer? Is there another better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `TodoCreateSerializer` you need to add `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` with a custom `queryset` that has the filtered tags of a user.

First, you will need to create a custom `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` that filter any objects to get only those who owned by the user.

```
class UserFilteredPrimaryKeyRelatedField(serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField):
    def get_queryset(self):
        request = self.context.get('request', None)
        queryset = super(UserFilteredPrimaryKeyRelatedField, self).get_queryset()
        if not request or not queryset:
            return None
        return queryset.filter(user=request.user)
```

(This is a generic one and can be used when filtering in objects by `user`)

Then you should use this one in you `TodoCreateSerializer`:

```
class TodoCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
    tags = UserFilteredPrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset= Tag.objects, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Todo
        fields = ('title', 'description', 'due_at', 'tags')
```

Comment: Recommend passing `many=True` as an argument to `UserFilteredPrimaryKeyRelatedField` to enable multi-select. Currently it only allows you to select just one Tag from a dropdown.

Comment: @AamirKhan, Oh I missed that! Edited.